# How to use publish profile to target different environment

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, .net-core

I would like to publish my app using all those 3 different predefined environment variables(Development, Staging, and Production), but I cannot figure out how to target different environment when creating the publish profile.

Since .NET Core doesn't support multi-version of web.config, I cannot use environmentVariable tag in config file to automate my publish.

I also tried launchSettings.json, everything seems fine in VS and I can run different environment locally. I just want to automate my publish process too, so when I use different publish profile and then different environment is targeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish profile is used by `dotnet publish` command, that only packs app+dependencies and makes them ready for deployment:

> **dotnet publish** compiles the application, reads through its dependencies specified in the project.json file and publishes the resulting set of files to a directory.

You specify Environment on target platform, where you do deployment, by using `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. I am not sure I understand you. What I am trying to do is to create Development, Staging, and Production publishing profile. What can I do to point ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development for Development(maybe called DevelopmentPub) publishing profile?

Comment: @BenzhiPan you cannot, publishing profile does not responsible for environment setup. You need to go on instance and set up environment there. As a workaround you may try to define different project.json files with different prepublish/postpublish scripts that will define different value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  and then publish the application using the specified project.json